# How to add more to a head on Jekyll

Tags: github, jekyll-theme

I have a GitHub hosted website, that is currently using a Jekyll theme, and running on HTML. The problem with this is I have to put

```
---
layout: default
---
```

Into the beginning, and that takes care of the head. But now, I can't add anything to the head, like important scripts I need to use. If anyone has experience with this, what can I do?

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution to this [on Jessica Reel's blog](https://jreel.github.io/per-page-custom-css-in-jekyll/).

To your `default.html` layout, in your head (or better yet at the end of your body, unless your scripts need to be in the head), add something like this:

```
  {% if page.custom_js %}
    {% for js_file in page.custom_js %}
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/js/{{ js_file }}.js"></script>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

Then in your page's front-matter, add:

```
custom_js:
- example-js-file-1
- example-js-file-2
```

Exact same principle works great for CSS, too.

I ended up taking it a step further with my own website since I use nested layouts. [Jekyll 3 so has a separate variable namespace for layout variables](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4123), so in the `head` of my main layout I specify first the layout's custom css *then* the page's custom css:

```
{% if layout.custom_css %}
  {% for stylesheet in layout.custom_css %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/{{ stylesheet }}.css">
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% if page.custom_css %}
  {% for stylesheet in page.custom_css %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/{{ stylesheet }}.css">
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

So you can see that it applies the custom css from the layout's front matter, *then* the custom css from the specific page's front matter, so that stuff cascades properly from general to specific styles.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a [Jekyll theme by GitHub](https://github.com/pages-themes/), you can populate the following file with the desired headers:

```
_includes/head-custom.html
```

Because this (AFAIK) overrides the theme-provided file, I recommend using the theme's own file as a starting point. In the *cayman* theme, for example, it looks like this ([link](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman/blob/master/_includes/head-custom.html), CC0):

```
<!-- start custom head snippets, customize with your own _includes/head-custom.html file -->

<!-- Setup Google Analytics -->
{% include head-custom-google-analytics.html %}

<!-- You can set your favicon here -->
<!-- link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ '/favicon.ico' | relative_url }}" -->

<!-- end custom head snippets -->
```

> Please note that I only tested this for the *cayman* and *architect* themes.

Answer (score -1):

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/layouts/#usage

> The first step is to put the template source code in `default.html`.

Create the following file `_layouts/default.html`

And then you can put whatever you want inside and customize the `head`, for example:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <a href="/">Home</a>
      <a href="/blog/">Blog</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <section>
      {{ content }}
    </section>
    <footer>
      &copy; to me
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, in the file _layouts/default.html, do I only put the head of what GitHub generates for me? Github generates some code for the template automatically on the website, and I can see it on its source code. So do I copy the automatically generated code, and put it in the said file?

Comment: You have to put everything in the `default.html` and use the variables as shown in the example. Feel free to read the documentation to get a full understanding of how the templates work.

Answer (score -2):

Jekyll view can be divided into two main parts on is layout and second is content.
Layouts are stored in `_layouts` folders, you can add your own layout there, you can even use other layouts to create a new one [check here](https://github.com/SLFree/rahulkantravi/blob/57f58712a9d39d0ce742243e49b783c6d6e823e2/_layouts/note.html#L1).

For each layout, you need to `{{ content }}`, this is the place where your page content will be added finally.

you can also add some more information in your content to access on the layout.
[Added info](https://github.com/SLFree/rahulkantravi/blob/57f58712a9d39d0ce742243e49b783c6d6e823e2/_posts/blogs/2016/2016-11-04-Story-Of-Colors.html#L2)

And get it on the main/layout page. [Get info](https://github.com/SLFree/rahulkantravi/blob/56a5718aca21ec6eb87eb96127cfac28c49230e1/blogs/index.html#L14)